# Confusing use of cte ,inner join and union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am confused about the use of inner join on the CTE here. what is in a as appears in the inner join at the end and what is in cte1 c?

```
WITH cte1 AS
      (SELECT id,geographyname,
              OriginalGoals,                
          ParentGeographyname,
          0 AS HierarchyLevel,
          paradigm
   FROM businessobject_RefinementMaster
   WHERE Id = @Geo
     UNION ALL
     SELECT a.id,
            a.geographyname,
            a.OriginalGoals,                
            a.ParentGeographyName,
            HierarchyLevel-1 AS HierarchyLevel,
            a.paradigm
     FROM businessobject_RefinementMaster a
     INNER JOIN cte1 c ON c.ParentGeographyname = a.geographyname
     AND c.paradigm=a.paradigm )
```

what will be the result of this query?

Comment: To understand, you can run each part stand-alone, and then build up the complete query.

Comment: This is a recursive CTE. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: what will be in the cte1 before inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **recursive CTE** (*hidden-RBAR*). I'll try to comment it in a way, that you can understand, what is going on:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
    /*
    This is called "anchor" and reads the "head" lines of a hierarchy
    */
    SELECT id,
        geographyname,
        OriginalGoals,                
        ParentGeographyname,
        0 AS HierarchyLevel,             --obviously this starts with a "0"
        paradigm
    FROM businessobject_RefinementMaster --The source-table
    WHERE Id = @Geo                      --You read elements with Id=@Geo. This is - probably - one single element
```

--The next SELECT will be "added" to the result-set

```
    UNION ALL

    /*
    The column-list must be absolutely the same (count and type) of the anchor
    */

    SELECT a.id,
        a.geographyname,
        a.OriginalGoals,                
        a.ParentGeographyName,
        HierarchyLevel-1 AS HierarchyLevel,                       --this is simple counting. Started with 0 this will lead to -1, -2, -3...
        a.paradigm
    FROM businessobject_RefinementMaster a                        --same source-table as above
    INNER JOIN cte1 c ON c.ParentGeographyname = a.geographyname  --Find rows where the name of the element is the parent-name of the former element
    AND c.paradigm=a.paradigm 
)

/*
Return the result-set
*/
SELECT * FROM cte1
```

The result should be a full recursive list of parents to a given element.